# Vimscript - get current line's indentation

Tags: vim

In *vim-script*, how would I go about reliably assigning to a variable the indentation for the current line?

`curpos()` to get the *col* does not seem reliable, as it only counts spaces, and I would need to take into account the tabstops as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `indent()` function; from [`:help indent()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#indent%28%29):

```
indent({lnum})  The result is a Number, which is indent of line {lnum} in the
                current buffer.  The indent is counted in spaces, the value
                of 'tabstop' is relevant.  {lnum} is used just like in
                getline().
                When {lnum} is invalid -1 is returned.
```

Comment: D'oh. Thank you so much, I could swear that for some reason it didn't work for me when I tried.